# On the eigenvalues of bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

**Definition**
Let $G=U\cup V$ is bipartite graph,  where $U$ and $V$ are disjoint sets of size $p$ and $q$, respectively. The complete bipartite graph denoted by $K_{p,q}$  is bipartite graph where every vertex in $U$ is connected to every vertex in $V$.

**Background**
It is known that the eigenvalues of complete bipartite graph $K_{p,q}$ are $\sqrt{pq}$, -$\sqrt{pq}$, and 0 with multiplicity $p+q-2$. (see Theorem 3.4 in [[1](http://file.zums.ac.ir/ebook/051-Graphs%20and%20Matrices%20(Universitext)-R.%20B.%20Bapat-1848829809-Springer-2011-175-$59.pdf)]).

**Question**
My question: Can this result generalized to regular bipartite graph?

In other words what is the eigenvalues of $d$-regular bipartite graph, where $d\leq p$? (Note that in this case $|U|=|V|=p$ ).

Any help will be useful!

Comment: @MorganRodgers Please note that if $\lambda$ is eigenvalues with multiplicity $l$, then -$\lambda$ is also eigenvalue with  multiplicity $l$.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no general result in this direction. Considering just connected cubic bipartite graphs of order 16 for example (38) one can see that all but two have distinct (multi)sets of eigenvalues.

Comment: @Jernej@MorganRodgers  Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @Jernej Could you please tell me what do you mean by (38)?

Comment: There are 38 cubic bipartite graphs of order 16.